# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin + Maven Flatten plugin + rtMavenDeployer. Is there a way to deploy flatten pom files?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

Using [Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins) for Jenkins pipeline is a bliss, just follow the docs and you are good. But then I introduced [Maven Flatten plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/) to resolve the pom.xml files for parent and submodules `mvn flatten:flatten`. The only thing I didn't got to work was the Maven deployer step to pickup the flatten pom files (.flatten-pom.xml) instead of original ones. I wonder if there is a way to specify that on deployer. A workaround may be using `mnv deploy` if repository is set in the pom file, but that overlaps Artifactory plugin, which is very convenient. Did someone had to deal with this already?

Answer (score 2):

In `rtMavenRun` stage, you can set the parent pom name:

```
rtMavenRun (
    ...
    pom: 'flatten-pom.xml',
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks @yahavi, but that property does not solve the problem with a single build.
1 - pom: <pom-location> is used to build the project, since .flatten-pom.xml is generated after it requires a hackish solution, which requires 2 steps: first compile and flatten;  second install deploy using pom: .flatten-pom.xml
2 - It worked for parent pom, but submodules did not get deployed into artifactory. So I had to configure flatten goal to keep <modules> in so that rtMaven could pickup them up. Turned out that it picked original pom.xml from submodules and not submodule/.flatten-pom.xml.